# Webservice and POST requests

Tags: http, post, nativescript

I have a web service written is ASP.NET which when tested with Postman with JSON content works fine. JSON is sent as Body is Postman

When trying to implement the same in Nativescript using HTTP Post, it fails.

When checking the IIS logs, the cs-method for Postman is correct as POST, but the cs-method for my Nativescript code is GET. An example from the IIS log entry is below:

> 2019-07-01 12:42:52 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx GET /Service.asmx/SaveAnswers -
>   443 - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
>   Mozilla/5.0+(Macintosh;+Intel+Mac+OS+X+10_13_6)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Brackets/1.14.0+Chrome/51.0.2704.103+Safari/537.36
>   - 200 0 0 62 2019-07-01 12:57:19 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx POST /Service.asmx/SaveAnswers - 443 - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx PostmanRuntime/7.15.0 -
>   200 0 0 359

My code to upload the JSON text is:-

```
function uploadJson(jsontxt){
        console.log(jsontxt);
        http.request = ({
              url: "https://myURL/Service.asmx/SaveAnswers",
              method: "POST",
              headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
              content: jsontxt
              }).then((response) => {
//                var result = response.content.toJSON();
//                console.log(result);
            console.log("Finished upload");
        }, (e) =>{
            console.log("JSON upload error: "+e);
        })
}
```

Changed the log IP address and my URL for security. I do not get any errors but do not understand how postman is POST and my script is GET in the logs

Comment: I'm not sure why you have an equal sign in between in your code (`http.request = ({...})`), was that intentional?

Comment: Unbelievable, I checked and rechecked the code and missed that one. Thank you so much.

Comment: This is where I love TypeScript ;)

Comment: Yep, I really need to move to Typescript